# How to see custom ligatures in a font file?

Tags: fonts, unicode, ligatures

I'm looking at a popular programming font [Fira Code](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode) that has a ton of custom ligatures, for combinations like `>>=` or `!==` that are not part of Unicode standard.

If I install the font and use it as a monospace font e.g. on an HTML page, browsers show the ligatures as advertised.

I suppose the glyphs for these ligatures are stored in a private use area. The font's site [suggests](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/wiki/Emacs-instructions#using-font-lock-keywords) that the ligatures are stored at `u+E100` and after.

I fail to find a way to see these glyphs, though! Character map utilities on both Windows and Linux don't show the ligatures anywhere. Direct entry of a character with a given code (e.g. E100) just shows me a rectangle with the code, as it should for a missing character.

- What tools would show me the glyphs of the ligatures, and their position in the font? Are they even stored at any code points?
- Is there a way to address a private ligature directly in a text, by a code point?